# NULLIF for Date Type

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql

Hello I have a sql update that requires a nullif for a date type. When I submit it without the nullif for an update the first time with a null statement it is fine and goes through but the second time always comes with an error.

```
UPDATE del_data.cncpt_rqst
        SET prpsd_prodn_dt=#{cncptDt}
        WHERE cncpt_rqst_id=#{cu.cncptRqstId}
```

However with the nullif such that `NULLIF(#{cncptDt},'')` it says that '' is of type text not date. Ive tried casting '' to date via ''::date, entering in null such that `(#{cncptDt},null)` and casting that null to date all to no avail.
Im bashing my head against this problem any help would be amazing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should cast the expression to date:

```
UPDATE del_data.cncpt_rqst
    SET prpsd_prodn_dt = nullif(#{cncptDt}, '')::date
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not possible to do `''::date`, you should cast first one to text instead:

```
postgres=# select nullif('2016-01-01'::date::text, '');
   nullif
------------
 2016-01-01
(1 row)
```

You can cast it to ::date afterwards - both null and textual representation of date are valid for such conversion.

Comment: At least in PostgreSQL 9.6 it is possible to cast to date.